# When i change fore color of a asp.net page it affect in other pages fore color

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

```
    .auto-style1 {
        height: 900px;
    }

</style>
```

Home

About Us

Admissions

Training Courses

```
  <li><a href="school-calendar.aspx">Centre Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<Font >
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="User  Login" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" style="z-index: 1; left: 430px; top: 211px; position: absolute; height: 28px; width: 133px; right: 199px; text-align: center" ForeColor="#585858"></asp:Label>
  </font>
  <p style="height: 275px">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" height="26px" style="z-index: 1; left: 537px; top: 342px; position: absolute" Text="Reset" width="54px" />
  </p>
```

> When i changes in some page such as office login page it looks that all of the pages fore color has change

Comment: You change the layout?

Comment: Your code does NOT show anything regarding forecolor, please post some usefull code.

Comment: i change height of content placeholder as well as the fore color of some control

Comment: where is the code which changes the forecolor? If you've got a problem with that, we'd need to see it. If it seems to be affecting all your pages then I'd guess you changed it in the master page, but you haven't shown us the master page.

Comment: If you have extra information, please use the Edit button to place it into your question. Code in comments is not easy to read, and also some people might not notice it. Also, please explain the context of the code i.e. where in your application it is located. Thankyou.

Comment: i have change in my question please look at that

Comment: You have destroyed the formatting changes I made and now your code is not properly visible